# Allowing SQL queries that view data not modify it

Tags: c#, sql

I am working on an application that will allow users to create queries on their own to view data in their database. However the stipulation is that the application should prevent any modification of the tables and data stored in the database. The Application will be written in C#. Any good suggestions of how this could be done? Possible idea that I have thought of:

- Parse SQL to filter for any reserve word that may alter data(i.e. insert, alter, ect)
- There maybe a setting that may prevent modification from this applications connection.

Any suggestion  to block any changes made from this application to prevent any chance of a user error or attempt to modify tables of data is much appreciated.

Comment: What strategy is used to access the database ?

Comment: @Vash .Net objects like those in System.Data.SqlClient

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should run your queries as a user that doesn't have write permission.

Comment: Can and/or how this be set in code before the statement is executed on the database

Comment: When you connect to a database, you specify a username.  You can specify and (existing) username you want.

Answer (score 4):

Any decent DBMS should have these protections already built in (at a per-user level). You just make sure the only access they have is read-only.

Then you don't have to worry about *anything* that they do. Let them try to insert, update and delete all they want.

It's a basic tenet of databases that they are responsible for their own security and integrity. You *never* leave that up to an external application since any monkey can write an application to connect to the database that *doesn't* follow the rules.

Comment: This system will be deliverable to a clients that may know what they are SQL wise but I want to protect the data from them. A DBMS would be overkill and also could not always be configured for them.

Comment: @user490250, I'm not sure I understand you. You stated they had a database (such as SQL Server or DB2). _That's_ the DBMS I'm talking about, not some separate product they have to install and configure. Their database will already have protections built in at a user level, just ensure that user doesn't have write access. What you're proposing seems to be an extra (totally unnecessary) layer of protection. My suggestion is to use the facilities you already have.

Comment: OK, I understand you better now. The problem with the suggestion is that the protections need to be on the application level due to the fact that users in another application should be able to commit changes not created by statements that are created by them though. If that helps clarify anything.

Comment: Then I would ensure that either (1) your application only logged on to the database as a single user "no_power" that had only read access or (2) if you needed specific user accounts, give each user two accounts (bob and bob_nopower), the second of which was readonly and make sure your app only ever allowed logins with the nopower variants.

Answer (score 2):

This needs to be handled at the user level rather than the query level.  When you set up your app, you'll need to make sure that the account used to run the queries does not have any dbwriter permissions.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually handled by giving users access to (non-updatable) views, but not to tables.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the best way is to create a user that can only do select on specified tables. And then use that user for connection.